# 2x ATI FireMV 2250 not working

Tags: troubleshooting, dell-vostro, amd-graphics-card

I've just bought 2x ATI FireMV 2250 cards from a reputable seller on ebay... one is a PCI-E x1 and the other is a PCI-E x16.

Problem is, neither works in my Dell Vostro 220 PC...

Both cards appear to not work.  Is there something I'm missing?

The seller used an anti-static bag for one of the cards, syaing that: "You Must connect this graphics board to the computer's power supply" but there's no socket for that, nor any indication.

I have contacted the seller, but thought I'd raise it here, as it seems strange that two cards can be non-functioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cards require extra PCI-E (6pin or 8pin) power and have the connectors on the end of the cards, then the cards will not work at all until that is connected.

If they don't have extra power connectors on the cards, then they should work as normal. Start with one card in the PCI-E 16x slot first and make sure that one works first.  Then I would try the next card by itself in the same slot and make sure it works.

Then once you know both work individualy, try them together and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I thought. I've checked the cards and there's definetly no slot for a power cable to be attached.  

The slot also works as this is the same slot that my existing graphics card uses.

Answer (score 0):

there is also a small chance the PCI-E is disable or set up incorrectly in the BIOS. Worth a look.

Comment: It should be working, as I had to remove a gigabit network card from the PCI-E 1x slot... But not with this graphics card.